# Difference between closure and pointer (c)

Tags: pointers, closures

In functional programming, `Ocaml` particularly, when a function is created, a reference to all `non-local variable` is created so that it can be used even if the non-local variable is out of scope and that is called **closure**.
And in `c` programming language, there is the notion of pointer which refers to the memory location of a variable.
The difference then between closures and pointers is in the scope. Is that all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement closures, the compiler/interpreter of `OCaml` must allocate a structure that contains a copy of all referenced variables and a pointer to the function. In `C`, a function pointer is just a pointer, so there is no allocation.